# Finding where $ f$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find all the $ z \in \Bbb {C}$ where $f (z)=\frac {z+1}{z-1}$ is analytic.

So I'm getting started with complex analysis, and being used to doing some real analysis I'm getting messed up. So in the book I'm reading, they just define the concept of an analytic function and mention Cauchy-Riemann conditions for every analytic function. But my question is, how should I treat the functions to see if they are analytic? Can I use old school derivation rules?

Comment: The differentiation rules of real variables, including the quotient rule, still apply. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g(z)=z+1$ and $h(z)=z-1$ are entire complex function; that is they are holomorphic over the entire complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. In particular they are analytic. Let now $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid g(z)\neq0\}=\mathbb{C}-\{1\}$. Then the quotient function

$$f(z)= \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$$

is analytic over $\Omega$. Then the set of complex number such that $f(z)$ is analytic or holomorphic is $\Omega$. In general complex functions over a domain $D$ is an algebra. The invertible elements are those functions such that have not zeros in that domain.

In your case $h(z)$ is invertible iff $z=1$ not belong to the domain.